# Get a column using sed and modify it

Tags: sed

I need to modify the 5 to 9 column directly in each line from a file.

Currently i'm doing this in a while loop, getting each column by line.
For example a line looks like:

```
echo "m.mustermann@muster.com;surnanme;givenname;displayname;1111;2222;3333;44(#44;(5555"

line_9=$(echo $line | awk -F "[;]" '{print $9}' | sed 's/[^0-9+*,]*//g')
```

Is there a possibility to do that with "sed -i" instead of awk

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure it can be done *generally* in sed, but you could definitely do it in awk:

```
… | awk -F";" '{ gsub("[^0-9]*","",$9); print $9 }'
```

If you really want to do it with sed, the expression will look something like:

```
… | sed -e 's,\(^[^;]*;[^;]*;[^;]*;[^;]*;[^;]*;[^;]*;[^;]*;[^;]*;[0-9]*\)[^0-9]*\([0-9]*\)[^0-9]*\([0-9]*\)[^0-9]*\([0-9]*\)[^0-9]*\([0-9]*\)[^0-9]*\([0-9]*\)[^0-9]*\([0-9]*\)[^0-9]*\([0-9]*\)[^0-9]*\([0-9]*\)\(.*\),\1\2\3\4\5\6\7\8\9,'
```

Comment: i need something like this  .... | awk -F";" '{ gsub("[^0-9]*","",$9); gsub("[^0-9]*","",$8); print $0 }' modify columns 5 to 9 and print all lines. Is it possible to print the delimiter too?

Comment: using this now ... print $1";"$2";"$3";"$4";"$5";"$6";"$7";"$8";"$9 is there a shorter way?

Comment: OFS sets the output field separator; awk has loops; try: `awk -F";" 'BEGIN {OFS=";" }{ for(i=5;i<10;++i)gsub("[^0-9]*","",$i); print }'`

Comment: can you please explain for what the "" is used before the $i

Comment: It's the replacement string. Consult the awk documentation for gsub: http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~oostr102/docs/nawk/nawk_92.html#IDX253

Answer (score 0):

For a version  with sed (posix) only

```
line_9="$(echo $line | sed 'H;x;s/^\(.\)\(\([^;]*;\)\{8\}\)\([^;]*\)/\2\1\4\1/;h;s/\(\n\).*\1/\1/;x;s/.*\(\n\)\(.*\)\1.*/\2/;s/[^0-9+*,]*//g;G;s/\(.*\)\(\n\)\(.*\)\2/\3\1/;h;s/.*//;x' )"
```